# JAVA Rest-Assured DSL redirects not working

Tags: java, http, rest, redirect, rest-assured

I am trying to configure my rest-assured tests to ignore redirects by using the following code:

```
RestAssured.config = config().redirect(redirectConfig().followRedirects(true).and().maxRedirects(20));
```

[Rest-Assured DSL](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage)

I am doing a PUT on a REST service and I get 302 HTML back because of the redirects, instead of the expected JSON type. Has anyone gotten this to work another away with rest-assured ?  Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jayway Link](http://www.jayway.com/2012/10/17/what-you-may-not-know-about-http-redirects/)

The above link explains that POST/PUT should get a response of a 303 instead of 302, and since I am getting a 302 on a PUT, rest assured does not support redirects for that. If I do GET and receive a 302, all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SessionId to omit redirection, this is what helped me:

```
String sessionId = RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic("user", "password").when().post("/x").andReturn().sessionId(); RestAssured.given().sessionId(sessionId).
```